# How can I use the windows cmd command "convert" in std::system?

Tags: c++, cmd, visual-studio-2019

Whenever I run this line:

```
system("convert -quality 80 captureqwsx.bmp captureqwsx.jpg");
```

this is what I get:

```
Invalid Parameter - 80
```

(not sure if that matters but I'm using visual studio 2019)

EDIT: when I run it from the command line it works perfectly fine

Comment: when type `convert /?` in cmd I get
`Converts a FAT volume to NTFS.`, probably not what you expect.

Comment: Windows `C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe` is not the same as the typical convert executable in Linux or macos systems from imagemagick.   Are you sure the imagemagick convert executable is in your search path before system32?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: What happens if you try to run `convert -quality 80 captureqwsx.bmp captureqwsx.jpg` from the command line? If you get the same response, then this has nothing to do with C++. (If you do get a successful response, please add that to your question.)

Comment: When I run it from the command line it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

The only `convert` command-line that is in the default `PATH` of a Windows system is a "Converts a FAT volume to NTFS" utility. If you run it from the command prompt with the parameters you provide, it in fact returns "Invalid Parameter - 80".

On Windows, the best option for launching a program from another program is to use `ShellExecuteEx`. It gives you the best control over the UI experience, especially when dealing with User Account Control (UAC) scenarios.

Here's an example helper function:

```
bool SpawnProcessAndWait( const wchar_t *szExePath,
    const wchar_t *szExeArgs,
    DWORD *pdwExitCode )
{
    if( !szExePath )
        return false;

    // Get working directory from executable path.
    WCHAR szDirectory[MAX_PATH] = {};
    wcscpy_s( szDirectory, szExePath );
    PathRemoveFileSpec( szDirectory );

    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW info = {};
    info.cbSize = sizeof( info );
    info.lpVerb = L"open";
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC | SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    info.lpFile = szExePath;
    info.lpParameters = szExeArgs;
    info.lpDirectory = szDirectory;
    info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    if( !ShellExecuteExW( &info ) )
        return false;
    
    // Wait for process to finish.
    WaitForSingleObject( info.hProcess, INFINITE );
    
    // Return exit code from process, if requested by caller.
    if( pdwExitCode )
        GetExitCodeProcess( info.hProcess, pdwExitCode );

    CloseHandle( info.hProcess );
    return true;
}
```

You should not assume that the specific utility you want to call is located in the search PATH. Instead, find a way to obtains it's actual location and use that as the `szExePath`.

> If you are in fact using ImageMagick, you can read Windows registry entries from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ImageMagick\Current` using the `BinPath` key which tells where to find `magick.exe`. Then you call `magick.exe` with `convert` as the first parameter.

> You likely want to provide a CWD that matches a different directory than use the CWD of the executable like this sample method does. You'd provide this parameter in `info.lpDirectory`.